# spark remote job through intellij

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

has any one used intellij to push spark jobs to remote cluster?
I am using spark 2.0.2 in standalone mode with hadoop 2.7.3. I can see application on 8080 as per config set through local intellij but none of executors are processing data, it seems that driver is misisng , any ideas?
here is the critical [image]log line:

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should provide more explanation on how you configured the run. Or are you asking for alternative ways of doing so?

Comment: i am using aws with all ports open to my laptop, using client mode deploy

Comment: it seem that there is  no connection to the driver which is my laptop, but all spark conigs as memory, executors, cores are amenable via intellij

Comment: changed deploy to cluster to avoid issues with the firewall, still the same issue